# How to compare an experimental study with amortized times

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, heaps, amortized-analysis, experimental-analysis

I have an implementation of a data structure I have to study for a group project (Fibonacci heaps if you're interested).
I'm asked to compare the theoretical results of the operations in amortized time, with the running times of my implementation.
Now my question: since amortized times are based on the fact that we look not just at a single operation, but at a series of operations, what can I do with my implementation to receive some experimental results that support (or not) my theoretical analysis?

Comment: Try to find Catherine McGeoch's Guide to Experimental Algorithmics in a  library near you.

Comment: I find your question to be *very* broad. What *can* you do? Everything you want! What *should* you do? I don't know, what do you already have? Which kind of data structure are you analysing, and which kinds of sequences?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare theory and experiment, you have to perform both analyses under the same assumptions.

Note that this includes what you measure. Since you did not analyse *time* in theory, there is little sense in measuring running times in the experiments. Use combinatoric measures you can count reliably and independently of the system and its load.